# Perforce - only for experts?

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v

I use P4V client.  I just want to do basic tasks; I don't want to use the command line and become an expert at Perforce.  The simple task I'm trying to accomplish is to copy the description and file list of a submitted changelist.  Is there any way to do this basic task?

Answer (score 7):

Using the command line does not make one an expert.

`p4 describe <changelist>` was a whole lot shorter to type than your question :)

Comment: You may want to use the "-s" flag to suppress the diff.

Comment: See, I am far from an expert even though I use the command line :)

Comment: I agree that you don't have to be an export to use the CLI, but it is a little awkward at first.  For instance, you have to have your P4PORT and P4CLIENT environment variables set.  Everytime someone sets up Perforce on a new computer, I have to help them with that stuff.  The visual client, on the other hand, has nice setup dialogs to help you through.

Comment: I know this question is ancient, but in case anyone is still using perforce: for the p4 client, it's easier to configure than the gui. Put a file `p4config` in the top-level directory of the wkspace, with (one variable per line): P4CLIENT={client_wkspace}, P4PORT={host:port}, P4USER={p4_user}, P4PASSWD={your_passwd}. Finally, set the env var P4CONFIG=p4config. ([see p4config](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/env.P4CONFIG.html)) This file is found when working in any subdir. If they can copy and edit a file (hopefully?), no further assistance should be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

There is a two step process in p4v, where you open the submitted changelist view and:

1. select the description of the changelist in question and copy it, then paste it to your destination.
2. open the node of the changelist and select the file names that you would like, copy those and paste them to your destination.

note that you can also print the changelist including submitted files from this view, if a hard copy is what you are after.

I agree that that p4win was better suited for this task, and that the command line solution is a bit less tedious.